# How to display a button on long press of a list item

Tags: android, listview, button, long-press

I need to display a delete button on long press of a list item..

I've got the code for long press.. but don't know how to code for displaying a button inside this long press...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got the answer...

**.xml file**

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgdelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

**.java file**

```
      lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            arg1.findViewById(R.id.imgdelete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to make that delete button invisible using code, or setting it's property in xml file. When the user clicks on `longpress` you have to make that delete button visible. After the delete action is completed, make that button invisible again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alert dialog. Here is an example

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                final CharSequence[] items = { "Delete Item" };


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        [CLASS_NAME].this);
                builder.setTitle("Delete Item");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Intent i;
                        switch (item) {
                        case 0:
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    SelectProfile.this);
                            builder.setMessage(
                                    "Are you sure you want to delete?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    // Prevents user to use "back button"
                                    .setPositiveButton(
                                            "Delete",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                                    //Todo code here
                                                }
                                            })
                                    .setNegativeButton(
                                            "Cancel",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            });
                            builder.show();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```